# Can the site get "J!" icon instead of "JO" icon?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Would it be possible to change icon of **Joomla!** SE site from **`JO`** to **`J!`**? Latter one is relatively well-established with **Joomla!**.

I understand that beta-phase and minor SE sites do not get distinctive skinning, but change to J! should be relatively easy for SE team.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a great idea. I wish I thought of it before. I'll update the icons today. They should be live after our next production build.

Comment: Let me thank you together with other Joomla fans!

Comment: I can still see old icon at http://cdn.sstatic.net/joomla/img/favicon.ico which is projecting into **Accounts** tab in network profile. But it is possible (I think) this will automatically correct itself after a day or two as server providing static images will update its cache. I will check again.

Comment: @miroxlav - works fine for me. I'm seeing the [new icon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/joomlameta/img/favicon.ico?v=ee03d0e09a9c). Try force refreshing (CTRL + F5) or clearing your cache

Comment: @Lodder – I know Ctrl+F5 very well :) I have just re-checked it with another browser, the old icon is still here (btw you checked different link). But let's wait a bit :)

Comment: @miroxlav - Fair enough. I sometimes get the same problem with some of my sites. Normally I just wait a while or clear my cache completely :)

Comment: @miroxlav is the new icon showing up for you now? I know we server cache graphic assets. Also the icon for site lists(inbox, network sites) are done in an image instead of using favicon.ico. We have to rebuild it every time a site's favicon is updated. I'm seeing the new icons now BTW.

Comment: @Jin – checked a week later – new icons are now everywhere, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Ahh you're referring to the favicon. Didn't have any idea what you mean till I looked around properly :)

Yes, totally agree with you. `J!` would be better. I assume during beta that the favicon must be that generic icon with 1 or 2 letters representing the site which is fine. But when the JSE site has passed beta, I think perhaps the Joomla logo itself should be used (if allowed).

Comment: technically there are possibly more icons, but they all look the same: (1) the favicon (2) site icon in list of SE sites in dropdown menu (3) icon at [StackEchange sites page](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) (4) meta.joomla.stackexchange icon (black) (5) sites list in your profile and maybe some more

Comment: I do not see any reason why even beta should have "JO". Beta sites have 2 or 3 characters (see other sites). The same is for minor SE sites which do not get their own icons longer time after beta phase. So if this icon will be with us longer time, why not to adjust it? The sooner, the better.

Comment: I'm going to assume we don't get control of some aspects of the site design during beta, this being one.  As much as it would be appropriate to change, it just might not be an option.

Comment: @Michael none of us can fix it for sure, but I don't think it hurts to ask!

Comment: @Michael - we should be able to change it. I'm not sure if we can do it after or during Beta but the Wordpress SE site has done it.

Answer (score 0):

agreed. JO is odd to me. J! would be great if we get two characters.